# Load or functional testing of GWT app using JMeter

Tags: gwt, jmeter, load-testing

I am new to JMeter. I wanted to do some functional testing of my GWT application using JMeter. 
Does it support GWT testing? For example I would like to write a script that might check if the login module of my GWT application is doing good or not. 
Please let me know if we have some sort of documentation specific to GWT testing with JMeter.

Thanks a million.

-- 
Mohyt

Answer (score -1, accepted):

JMeter is not the right tool for GWT-testing.

From [jmeter homepage](http://jakarta.apache.org/jmeter/index.html):

> JMeter is not a browser. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.

In clear words: jmeter doesn’t load your gwt-application.

I would recommend [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) for browser based testing. Or just use JUnit with GWTTestCase for functional testing inside your IDE.

Comment: It depends whether you want to test the server part or the client, too. In the first case, JMeter should work.

Answer (score 1):

There is a commercial solution called UbikLoadPack which offers a plugin for Apache JMeter to load test GWT and GWT RPC applications.

You can easily record, variabilize and replay GWT and GWT RPC based applications with standard knowledge of Apache JMeter.

See this blog for a tutorial:

- http://www.dzone.com/links/load_testing_gwtrpc_applications_with_ubik_load_p.html

And this for commercial infos:

- http://www.ubikloadpack.com/

Answer (score 0):

I think GWTRpcComLayer might be useful for your case: http://code.google.com/p/gwtrpccommlayer/

Answer (score 0):

if you wanna test gwt client side then you have to use junit because jmeter does not support javascript and if you want to test at backend side than you have JMeter send it HTTP requests via HttpClient (http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) or something similar.